# I want to Create an Anonymous function which will be called in another function

Tags: javascript

I want to Create an Anonymous function which will be called in another function. I tried this, why is it not working

```
function parent (i){
   retrun function () {
       console.log(i)
    }
}

var anonym = parent(2);

function callback (fn){
   fn();
}


callback(anonym);
```

Answer (score 2):

there is spelling mistake in your return statement.. check **return** spelling,

```js
function parent (i){
   return function () {
       console.log(i)
    }
}

var anonym = parent(2);

function callback (fn){
   fn();
}


callback(anonym);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function parent(i) {
  function callback(fn); 
  alert("The function called 'function parent' has been called.");
}

function callback(fn) {
  alert("The function called 'function callback' has been called.");
}
```